# Preloader modal Framework 7 unchangeable

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7, modalpopup

I have been trying to solve this small issue of changing the modal for the Preloader popup to be bigger so the whole number of A301 can be seen, however I don't understand how Framework 7 design works cus I've been changing many times and it doesn't work.

```
openCustomPreloader: function () {
        var app = this.$app;
        app.dialog.preloader('Your Room Number is <p style="font-size:200px;line-height:0px;">A301</p>Checking In');
        setTimeout(function () {
          app.dialog.close();
        }, 6000);
      },
```

[image]

Comment: target modal width in index page to change the width. that should work fine

Comment: if you want have greater control then go for popup instead or preloader.

Answer (score 0):

You can change width of dialog by overriting dialog css.

Try to make `.dialog` width to auto